# 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to generalize some code to avoid repeating it over and over. My idea is, starting from this

```js
    class Entity {
      static create(): Entity { return new Entity(); }
      static save(entity: Entity): void {}
    }
    
    class Crud {
      create(): void {
        Entity.save( Entity.create() );
      }
    }
```

generalize the code like this:

```js
    class Entity {
      static create(): Entity { return new Entity(); }
      static save(entity: Entity): void {}
    }
    
    class Crud<T extends Entity> {
      create(): void {
        T.save( T.create() );
      }
    }
```

but I must be overlooking something since some problems appear:

a) The generic parameter T is grayed out indicating it's not referenced

b) When accessing static methods (.create() and .save()) from T, it says "'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here"

What am I doing wrong? What would be a better/working approach? (I hope the example is not oversimplified)

**UPDATE**: turned code samples into text instead of images

Comment: Please paste your code instead of images.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 1):

T is a generic type, it is not a value, you can pass a parameter into `create` method type T and typescript will know, that this parameter extends `Entity`

```
create(someEntity: T): void {
    someEntity.save(someEntity.create())
}
```

And you should understand that `someEntity` is an Object, not a class or a type. Object of Entity or some class that extend Entity

Comment: Ok, i got you, won't do this next time

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to look into my problem.

Notice how "save()" and "create()" are class methods, not instance methods. I need to call them through the type (i.e. Entity.save() in the first example) not through an instance, that's why I expected T.save() to work.

Comment: So you can use your class method, just make `Entity.save(Entity.create())`. You can't call method of the type, that makes no sense.
Also you can add add instance of Entity in constructor and use its method
`constructor(someEntity: T) {
    this.someEntity = someEntity
}
create(): void {
    this.someEntity.save(this.someEntity.create())
}`

Comment: `Entity.save(Entity.create())` is what I want to generalize.

If I do:

`class CatCrud extends Crud<Cat> {}`

Then I want `CatCrud.create()` to call `Cat.save(Cat.create())`

But if I do:

`class DogCrud extends Crud<Dog> {}`

Then I want `DogCrud.create()` to call `Dog.save(Dog.create())`

Regarding calling a method on a type being a nonsense, Entity is a type (it is a class) and I can do Entity.create(), i.e.

Unfortunately passing an instance of the entity through the constructor is of no help here since the methods I need to call are "class methods" not "instance methods".

Comment: So why don't you want to declare a variable type: T (that already extends Entity) in your Crud class and use this variable?

Comment: Declaring

`constructor (private entityInstance: T) { }`

and then trying to use it like

`this.entityInstance.create()`

would not work because `create()` is a "class method" (it's declared as `static`) and I would be trying to use it as an "instance method".

The Entity is not mine: it's provided by a framework and I can't change it.

Comment: I took a different approach: leveraging that the repository instance also has .create() and .save() instance methods, I'm injecting the repository in the constructor like this `constructor(private myRepository: Repository<T>)` and then doing `this.myRepository.create()` and `this.myRepository.save()`. Not exactly what I intended to do, but gets the job done.

Thanks a lot for your help :)